# cURL doesn't follow redirect automatically for an API running in Docker

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, http-redirect

I have two very simple FastAPI APIs running in their respective docker containers with corresponding ports opened (ports `8000` and `8001`). The code can be found [here](https://github.com/abhinavkulkarni/Stackoverflow-Issues/tree/2022-06-28).

Both have an `/index` endpoint, the 2nd APIs `/index` endpoint redirects to the 1st.

The first API's `/index` endpoint looks as follows:

```py
@app.get("/index")
async def index():
    return JSONResponse(content={"message": "Welcome to my API 1!"}, status_code=200)
```

The 2nd API's `/index` endpoint looks like the following:

```py
@app.get("/index")
async def index2():
    api1_url = os.getenv('MYAPI1_URL')
    return RedirectResponse(url=f"{api1_url}/index")
```

where `MYAPI1_URL=http://{HOST_IP}:8000`

However, when I cURL `/index` endpoint of 2nd API, I am not automatically redirected to `/index` endpoint of 1st API.

```bash
# No response without -L flag
$ curl -X GET -i http://${HOST_IP}:8001/index

HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
date: Thu, 30 Jun 2022 09:47:19 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 0
location: http://192.168.0.202:8000/index

# Using -L flag does get the intended response
$ curl -X GET -i http://${HOST_IP}:8001/index -L

HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
date: Thu, 30 Jun 2022 09:47:38 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 0
location: http://192.168.0.202:8000/index

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Thu, 30 Jun 2022 09:47:38 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 34
content-type: application/json

{"message":"Welcome to my API 1!"}
```

However, if I put some other URL in the `RedirectResponse` (for e.g. `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1`), I do get a JSON response without needing to specify `-L` flag. What gives?

Comment: So your real question is the opposite of the title - why does curl automatically redirect when `-L` is missing? What's the URL that automatically redirects?

Comment: What's the actual *full* HTTP response in each case? Post the full text, not just the body. Perhaps the headers are different.

Comment: Please post the full HTTP response. which can be loaded by the command `curl -X GET -i http://{HOST_IP}:8001/index`.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post with full response.

Comment: It would be helpful if you include the actual response/request sequence of the `RedirectResponse` that gives the differing behavior (and code for that single endpoint). Having to supply `-L` is the expected behavior, so if curl follows a redirect without that, that's the interesting part - the part you've included is the expected behavior.